# How to drag and drop an image on top of a existing image using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now, I'm building a functional chessboard that you can play games on but I'm having troubles with figuring out how to get the chess pieces to drag and drop on top of some of the green dots.

Picture of problem:
[image]

I'm trying to drag this chess piece and place it over one of the two dots, and I don't know how to go about doing that. Whenever I try to drag the chess piece on top of the green dot my chess piece ends up disappearing. How do I fix this problem?

The green dots are inside of some div tags if that helps. The green dots are set to display none and only appear when you click on the pawn pieces. I just need people to look at the 5th, 6th, and 7th rows where the white pawns are located at and where the green dots are located at, and that's it.

I only setup some drag events for one of the div's in each row which are the 5th and 6th rows, and I also setup a drag event for the first white pawn on the 7th row, and I was just testing it out on one section of my board which you can see from the image above. Here's my...

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nitroadam1233/ckn216px/2/

**JavaScript Code:**

```
//dragging white pawns
function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function drag(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
}
  
function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var newNode = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);

    clearChildren(event.target);
    event.target.appendChild(newNode);
}

function clearChildren(el) {
    while (el.firstChild) {
      el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
    }  
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="board">
          
            <!-- 1st row -->
            <div><img src="images/black_rook.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_knight.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_bishop.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_queen.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_king.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_bishop.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_knight.png"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_rook.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
          
            <!-- 2nd row-->
            <div><img src="images/black_pawn.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="black_pawns" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_pawn.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="black_pawns" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_pawn.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="black_pawns" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_pawn.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="black_pawns" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_pawn.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="black_pawns" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_pawn.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="black_pawns" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_pawn.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="black_pawns" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/black_pawn.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="black_pawns" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            
            <!-- 3rd row empty-->
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
          
            <!-- 4th row empty-->
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares"></div>
          
            <!-- 5th row empty-->
            <div class="empty_squares5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
          
            <!-- 6th row empty-->
            <div class="empty_squares5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
            <div class="empty_squares5"><img src="images/greenDot.png" height="40px" width="60px"></div>
          
            <!-- 7th row-->
            <div class="seventh_squares"><img src="images/white_pawn.png" draggable="true" id="item1" ondragstart="drag(event)" onmousedown="dontShowDots(event)" onclick="showDots()" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div class="seventh_squares"><img src="images/white_pawn.png" draggable="true" id="" class="" onmousedown="dontShowDots2(event)" onclick="showDots2()" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div class="seventh_squares"><img src="images/white_pawn.png" draggable="true" id="" class="" onmousedown="dontSD3(event)" onclick="showDots3()" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div class="seventh_squares"><img src="images/white_pawn.png" draggable="true" id="" class="" onmousedown="dontShowDots4(event)" onclick="showDots4()" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div class="seventh_squares"><img src="images/white_pawn.png" draggable="true" id="" class="" onmousedown="dontShowDots5(event)" onclick="showDots5()" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div class="seventh_squares"><img src="images/white_pawn.png" draggable="true" id="" class="" onmousedown="dontShowDots6(event)" onclick="showDots6()" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div class="seventh_squares"><img src="images/white_pawn.png" draggable="true" id="" class="" onmousedown="dontShowDots7(event)" onclick="showDots7()" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div class="seventh_squares"><img src="images/white_pawn.png" draggable="true" id="" class="" onmousedown="dontShowDots8(event)" onclick="showDots8()" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
          
            <!-- 8th row-->
            <div><img src="images/white_rook.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/white_knight.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/white_bishop.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/white_queen.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/white king.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/white_bishop.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/white_knight.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>
            <div><img src="images/white_rook.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" height="65px" width="65px"></div>

            <script src="interactive.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is much that can be optimized with the code, but to solve the specific question, the drop function needs to be modified as follows, with comments indicating the purpose behind the two new lines...

```
function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var newNode = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);

    // Clear the drag square of the piece IMG...
    clearChildren( document.getElementById(data).parentNode );
    
    clearChildren(event.target);
    event.target.appendChild(newNode);
    
    // Finally, remove the "empty_squares5" class from the drop square.
    event.target.classList.remove( 'empty_squares5' );
}
```

Comment: The way you showed me worked, but I was just wondering is there a way I can apply this to the rest of the pawn pieces? @Trentium

Comment: @AdamBreslin "There is much that can be optimized with the code...".  Just about everywhere that you have repetitive `<div>`'s and specific references to array elements in `arrayDots` or `arraySeventhSquares` are areas that can benefit from appropriate data structures and loops that represent the pieces and their movement.  These data representations can then be used to refresh the DOM... Since the data issue is separate from this thread's question, please pose another question asking about a simpler way of building and managing the 64 `<div>`'s that represent the board and I will elaborate...

Comment: I just posted a new question that asks how I can optimize my code. Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68976802/how-do-i-optimize-my-javascript-code-that-i-currently-have @Trentium